# How to resolve the problem with a circular import using python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

i'm learning how to create restful api in python using flask-restful and jwt, and now i have an import problem. Here is the error and my source code
the error:
py .\api.py

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Amoungui\Documents\Projects\API-playlist-master\api.py", line 4, in 
from app import app, api
File "C:\Users\Amoungui\Documents\Projects\API-playlist-master\app.py", line 4, in 
from security import auth,identity
File "C:\Users\Amoungui\Documents\Projects\API-playlist-master\security.py", line 1, in 
from User import User
File "C:\Users\Amoungui\Documents\Projects\API-playlist-master\User.py", line 1, in 
from app import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Amoungui\Documents\Projects\API-playlist-master\app.py)**

this the files code
index.py:

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_jwt import jwt_required
from app import app, api
from CustomerRepository import CustomerRepository as Repository

items = Repository.findAll()

class UserController(Resource):
    @jwt_required()
    def get(self, id):
        item = next(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == id, items), None)
        return {'item': item}, 200 if item else 404
    
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        new_item = {'tel': data['tel'],'password':data['password']}
        items.append(new_item)
        return new_item
    
    def delete(self, id):
        global items
        items = list(filter(lambda x:x['name']!=id,items))
        return items

    def put(self, id):
        data = request.get_json()
        item = next(filter(lambda x:x['id'] == id, items),None)
        if item is None:
            item = {'tel':data['tel'], 'password':data['password']}
            items.append(item)
        else:
            item.update(data)

class ItemList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return{'item':items}

api.add_resource(UserController,'/items/<string:name>')
api.add_resource(ItemList,'/items')


app.run(port=4000,debug=True)
```

the app.py where I have all the configuration

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_restful import Api
from security import auth,identity
from flask_jwt import JWT
import urllib

app = Flask(__name__)

database_name = "API"
mongodb_password = ""
DB_URI = "mongodb+srv://m001-student:"+ urllib.parse.quote(mongodb_password) +"@cluster0.hr17o.mongodb.net/{}?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(database_name)
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = DB_URI

app.secret_key = '#0#'
api = Api(app)
jwt = JWT(app, auth, identity)#/auth

db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)
```

CustomerRepository.py

```
from flask import make_response, request, jsonify
from User import User

class CustomerRepository():
    
    def findAll():
        users = []
        for user in User.objects:
            users.append(user)
            
        return make_response(jsonify(users), 200)
```

User.py:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Document):
    customer_id = db.IntField()
    tel = db.StringField()
    password = db.IntField(6)
    
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "customer_id": self.customer_id,
            "tel": self.tel,
            "password": self.password,
        }
```

security.py

```
from User import User
from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp

def auth(tel,password):
    user = User.findByName(tel)
    if user and safe_str_cmp(user.password,password):
        return user

def identity(payload):
    id = payload['identity']
    return User.find_by_id(id)

def findByName(number):
    customer_obj = User.objects(tel=number).first()
    if customer_obj:
        return customer_obj

def findById(customer_id):
    customer_obj = User.objects(customer_id=customer_id).first()
    if customer_obj:
        return customer_obj
```

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have `api.add_resource(UserController,'/items/<string:name>')` in `index.py`. But I don't see `api` being defined or imported from anywhere. You may start there.

Comment: This is a cyclic import error. It is very common to have such errors.  Instead of importing app, try `current_app`. 
`from flask import current_app`
and use `current_app` everywhere instead of `app`. That should resolve the cyclic dependency issue.

Comment: I move the app into the index file and app file and replace it with `current_app`  but no result. I have the same error

Comment: can you paste your code here to see how you arrived to fix this bug, please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a new approche, that's work fine
app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

index.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource
from Customer import Customer

class HelloWorld(Resource): 

    def get(self):
        return Customer.findAll(Customer)
    
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        
        customer = Customer(
                    tel=data['tel'], 
                    password=data['password']
                )
        customer.save()     
    
class Multi(Resource):
    def get(self, num):
        return {'result': num*10}
```

Customer.py

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response
from mongoose import db

class Customer(db.Document):
    customer_id = db.IntField()
    tel = db.StringField()
    password = db.IntField(6)
    
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "customer_id": self.customer_id,
            "tel": self.tel,
            "password": self.password,
        }

    def findAll(self):
        users = []
        for user in self.objects:
            users.append(user)
            
        return make_response(jsonify(users), 200)
```

routes.py

```
from index import HelloWorld, Multi
from flask_restful import Api
from app import app
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(Multi, '/multi/<int:num>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

mongoose.py

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from app import app
import urllib

database_name = "API"
mongodb_password = ""
DB_URI = "mongodb+srv://m001-student:"+ urllib.parse.quote(mongodb_password) +"@cluster0.hr17o.mongodb.net/{}?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(database_name)
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = DB_URI


db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)
```